# How to access CUPS variables from java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am trying to access the variables in CUPS in cloud foundry. Currently I have my values set as environment variables.

In java I use the following code to retrieve environment variables.

```
String variableName = System.getenv("variableName");
```

I am following this [link](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2014/10/keeping-secrets-cloud-application-access-credentials-private-data/) and it talks about creating a user provided service and retrieve data from there.

**Example**

```
cfenv = require("cfenv")

var localVCAP = require("./local-vcap.json")

var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv({vcap: localVCAP})
var creds  = appEnv.getServiceCreds(/session-secret/) || {}

console.log("session secret is:", creds.secret)
```

How can I do simliar thing but in java? "How to retrieve cloud foundry CUPS varibles into java?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once created, user-provided service instances behave like service instances created through the marketplace only. By Default all the services binded to the application is available in environment variable VAP_SERVICES.

Bind the CUPS service to your application, then read the VCAP_SERVICES System property in your java code.

```
String vcapServices = System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
```

This value is a JSON that has a all the binded services related information. You can parse this JSON to read your CUPS service properties.
Sample variable would look like

```
{
    "VCAP_SERVICES": {
        "user-provided": [
            {
                "sec": {
                    "key": "1234567890"
                },
                "label": "user-provided",
                "name": "sample-cups-secret",
                "syslog_drain_url": "",
                "tags": []
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: So, would I do "String vcapServices = System.getProperty("VCAP_SERVICES");" and it will return all the values in json format? or is it String label= System.getProperty("label"); and get the return value of "user-provided"

Comment: String vcapServices = System.getProperty("VCAP_SERVICES"); would return you the VCAP_SERVICES contents. Then you need to parse the JSON to get the required data in that.

Comment: I followed your method String vcapServices = System.getProperty("VCAP_SERVICES"); and I also did system.out.println(vcapServices + "@@@@@@"); I receive a null value? But I have a service bind to my app. Main goal is with your example I want to print out the "key" value.

Comment: Oops sorry, could you try String VCAP_SERVICES = System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"); If you are still not receiving check environment using cf env [appname] command

Comment: That worked, Is it possible to get the values individually? Instead of having it all printed out? ex; with your example how would I be able to just have "key" printed out

Comment: Parse it to a JSON object using Jackson. CupsProperties properties = new ObjectMapper().readValue(VCAP_SERVICES, CupsProperties.class). Write your own CustomProperties.java class according to your properties. Then you can get the properties from that object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143115/discussion-between-jesse-and-praneeth-ramesh).

Comment: Would there be a similar means of accessing the environment variables of cups from the shell?